# Explode data in PHP using custom condition

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Can anyone please help me?  I have a data in a column called `column_hide` the data is `0,1`

I want to explode and put a condition if attribute `data-column` same with value in `column_hide` I added `down class`
and here is my error screenshot

[image]

```
<div class="pull-right">
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis <?= ($value==0 ? "" : "") ?>" data-column="0">PARTS NO</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="1">REVISED NO</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="2">LATEST NO</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="3">DESCRIPTION</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="4">IN FIFO</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="8">TOTAL QTY</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="9">STOCK J</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="10">STOCK B</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="11">STOCK S</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="12">STOCK X</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="13">STORAGE</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="14">LAST OPNAME</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="15">DISCONTINUED</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="16">MESIN</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="17">SRP PRICE</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="18">SRP COD</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="20">MANAGER</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="21">DIRECTOR</button>
<button style="font-size:7pt" class="toggle-vis" data-column="22">NOTE</button>
```

Comment: are these values coming from database?

Comment: @Alex yes , here data in database  `0,1`

Comment: right but each has its own value, so 0 OR 1 right? what does the table structure look like? does it contain the name e.g. `STOCK X` and the column id e.g. `12` and the column hide as well?

Comment: @Alex no, it can be filled `0,1,2,3 till 22` and if the value same with data-column attribut i want add class `downs`

Comment: strange schema. you should have made this all 1 table with columns `column_name` (varchar 50), `column_id` (int), and `hidden` (bool). then you could generate this all with a simple foreach. that is what i suggest doing. storing multi purpose string data/serialized data is never a good idea

Comment: in any case, you said `column_hide` can be 0-22 so i assume the ids in that string are the only ones you want to add `downs` to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of doing it. Example:

```
<?php

$string = '0,1,3';

$array = explode(',', $string);

// METHOD 1
// better performance

$flip = array_flip($array); // only have to do this once

if (isset($flip[3])) {
    echo 'true';
}

// OR

// METHOD 2
// probably less efficient

if (in_array(3, $array)) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Of course the if logic has to be repeated per "column". The number, in this example 3, will have to be hard coded per each button.

Still suggest making a table like I said in the comments.